# Whats wrong in my sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I'm trying to create a new table, but I don't know what I did wrong when creating the table.

SQL query:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wan_ecommerce;
USE wan_ecommerce
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
 user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT,
 user_name varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT,
 user_password_hash varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT,
 user_email varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT,
 user_active tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT,
 user_activation_hash varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
 user_password_reset_hash char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
 user_password_reset_timestamp bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
 user_rememberme_token varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
 user_failed_logins tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT,
 user_last_failed_login int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
 user_registration_datetime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 user_registration_ip varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY user_name (`user_name`),
 UNIQUE KEY user_email (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data';
```

When I run this I get an error. I've  added `;` after `use wan_ecommerce`;, but I'm still getting:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '
>
> user_name varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT,
>
> user_passwo' at line 2

What am I doing wrong here?

How can I solve this?

Comment: You miss a `;` at end of `USE wan_ecommerce`

Comment: use semi colon in the end of your second line.

Comment: USE wan_ecommerce ---> ; <-- (missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use semicolon to terminate each statement.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wan_ecommerce;
USE wan_ecommerce; -- <----- semi colon was missing
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
-- ....
```

Comment: Change `user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT,` to `user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'some description about the field here',`. The key word `COMMENT` is used to add comment on the field or table.

Comment: And if you don't want to add comments per field, just remove those `'COMMENT'`s from your script and execute.

Answer (score 0):

The 'COMMENT' is a keyword. If you use it,you must to add a description to flowing 'COMMENT',like this code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wan_ecommerce;
USE wan_ecommerce
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
 user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
 user_name varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'name',
 user_password_hash varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'password_hash',
 user_email varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'email',
 user_active tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'active',
 user_activation_hash varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'activation_hash',
 user_password_reset_hash char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'password_reset_hash',
 user_password_reset_timestamp bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'password_reset_timestamp',
 user_rememberme_token varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'rememberme_token',
 user_failed_logins tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'failed_logins',
 user_last_failed_login int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'last_failed_login',
 user_registration_datetime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 user_registration_ip varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY user_name (`user_name`),
 UNIQUE KEY user_email (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data';
```

If you don't need this 'COMMENT',you can remove it.The code like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wan_ecommerce;
USE wan_ecommerce

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
 user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 user_name varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 user_password_hash varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 user_email varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 user_active tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 user_activation_hash varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 user_password_reset_hash char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 user_password_reset_timestamp bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 user_rememberme_token varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 user_failed_logins tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 user_last_failed_login int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 user_registration_datetime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 user_registration_ip varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY user_name (`user_name`),
 UNIQUE KEY user_email (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data';
```