# PHPMyAdmin - Database Backtrace Errors

Tags: database, wordpress, localhost, backtrace

I was having trouble uploading a website the other day to live from local MAMP server due to what i think was coalition issues after going through some threads here I had made some changes to the coalition names through find and replace. Though i researched and tried several coalition formats on the forum here, nothing seemed to work.

Finally I got the live website to come online this morning decided by using a basic wordpress install and had then decided to install by exporting it through WP-Migration (Wordpress Migration Plugin) locally and importing the .wpress file on the now live site, only now when i look back into logging into local site, the database seems corrupted and tables are not showing, even though they are in the structure...

[Wordpress Database Selected and available sub tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1otrW.png)

when i click on other tables the following errors show up:

[these errors are coming up on every other table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkXnl.png)

have I lost my content from the build locally? I have not made a duplicate of the database but i did make a backup of the wordpress folder.

Any help appreciated.

After a tea break and deciding to backtrace what i was doing last night, I got an old .sql file from my download folder I happened to have that I can work with and I've come back to where I was yesterday and have done the following.

I tried to upload this file into a new database on PHPmyadmin
the file was giving last nights coalition errors and no tables were uploading.
I adjusted the version of my MAMP to the older version
I did a serach and replace to utf8
I uploaded  this new .sql file and a new error now appears that I recall from last night (below) while some tables now upload

```
Error
SQL query:
--
-- Database: `wordpress`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `codeneric_phmm_comments`
--
CREATE TABLE `codeneric_phmm_comments` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `content` text COLLATE utf8 NOT NULL,
  `project_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `attachment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `wp_user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `wp_author_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8
MySQL said: Documentation

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8'
```

[I did a search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069928/whats-wrong-in-my-sql-query) on the stack overflow site to discover a possible solution in adjusting the commas's to colan's which may relate to the second screenshot issue though I'm not sure.

Comment: Questions about wordpress website administration are better served on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: hi, I've been directed to a phpMyAdmin forum. where is that?

Comment: @JustinR. that is incorrect. The question was posted on that stack and I personally closed it as it's a PHPMyAdmin question not a WP question. Those tables could just as easily be Joomla tables or Drupal tables, it would be the same

Comment: I've added some additional comment that may make this clearer.